# Python Eve - Query Embedded Data Relation

Tags: python, eve

I have the following resource defined:

```
item = {
    'wrapper': {
        'type': 'dict',
        'schema': {
            'element': {
                'type': 'objectid',
                'data_relation': {
                    'resource': 'code',
                    'field': '_id',
                    'embeddable': True,
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

When I try to query using the objectid, I get empty list.

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/item?where={"wrapper.element":"5834987589b0dc353b72c27d"}
```

5834987589b0dc353b72c27d is the valid _id for the element.

If I move the data relation out of the embedded document I can query it as expected

Is there anyway to do this with an embedded data relation?

Comment: Are you sure you have an `item` inserted with `5834987589b0dc353b72c27d` as value for wrapper.element?

Comment: This is functionality still needed.Refer this link https://github.com/pyeve/eve-sqlalchemy/issues/100

Comment: @bigbounty, the issue mentioned is not about the same thing. This one is just about filtering based on a objectid data_relation value, and the other is about embedding "sub-sub" documents as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes, I do have an item with the ID that I am querying for

Comment: can we have the field in data relation set to some other field in referenced resorce? for example can I have 'id' instead of '_id'? Assuming that I have a field in the referenced table by that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem where the `_id` was being stored as a string rather than an `ObjectId()`, this broke the query

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested with `eve==0.7.1` and it works as expected by filtering with `?where={"wrapper.element" : "<your_objectid>"}`, as you said.

Comment: Tested on 0.7.3 and it doesn't work for me, maybe it is some other part of my schema that is busting this. I will try a bare bones application